# from arXiv ID to BibTeX entry

Tags: perl, atom-feed, bibtex

How can I write a robust Perl script that will generate a BibTeX entry for an arXiv ID?

My guess is that I should use the [arXiv API](https://arxiv.org/help/api/) and parse its response with [XML::Atom](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Atom). It should give me the needed pieces of information to build a BibTeX entry.

Here is how I would start:

```
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Text::BibTeX::Entry;
use XML::Atom;

my $arxivid = "hep-ph/9609357";
my $url = "http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=" . $arxivid . "&start=0&max_results=1";
my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
my $response = $browser->get($url);
my $entry = Text::BibTeX::Entry->new();
```

Answers not using the arXiv API or XML::Atom are welcome too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a starting point using [`XML::Twig`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::Twig) to parse the downloaded XML file:

```
use feature qw(say);
use strict;
use warnings;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use Text::BibTeX;
use Text::BibTeX::Entry;
use XML::Twig;
use DateTime::Format::Strptime;
{
    my $arxivid = "hep-ph/9609357";
    my $url = "http://export.arxiv.org/api/query?search_query=" . $arxivid . "&start=0&max_results=1";
    my $browser = LWP::UserAgent->new();
    my $response = $browser->get($url);
    my $xml = $response->content;
    my $twig = XML::Twig->new->parse( $xml );
    my $title = $twig->get_xpath ( '//entry/title',0 )->text;
    my @authors;
    for my $node ( $twig->findnodes( '//entry/author/name' )) {
        push @authors, $node->text;
    }
    my $doi = $twig->get_xpath ( '//entry/link[@title="doi"]',0 )->att('href');
    my $published = $twig->get_xpath ( '//entry/published',0 )->text;
    my ( $year, $month) = parse_published( $published) ;

    my $entry = Text::BibTeX::Entry->new();
    $entry->set_metatype(BTE_REGULAR);
    $entry->set_type('article');
    $entry->set_key('article1');
    $entry->set( 'title', $title );
    $entry->set( 'author', join ' and ', @authors );
    $entry->set( 'year', $year );
    $entry->set( 'month', $month );
    $entry->set( 'doi', $doi );
    $entry->print(\*STDOUT);
}

sub parse_published  {
    my ( $published) = @_;

    my $parser = DateTime::Format::Strptime->new(
        pattern => '%FT%T%Z',
        time_zone => 'UTC',
        on_error => 'croak',
    );

    my $dt = $parser->parse_datetime($published);

    return ( $dt->year, $dt->month_name);
}
```

**Output**:

```
@article{article1,
  title = {Mixing-induced CP Asymmetries in Inclusive $B$ Decays},
  author = {Martin Beneke and Gerhard Buchalla and Isard Dunietz},
  year = {1996},
  month = {September},
  doi = {http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/S0370-2693(96)01648-6},
}
```

Comment: That's nice. What about the year and month?

Comment: @Bob There is a field `<published>1996-09-14T00:08:27Z</published>` in the XML file that could be used to extract year and month?

Comment: @Bob See my updated answer for an approach using `DateTime` to parse the `published` node